# how can a python program change itself'es code

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can the dictionary of **contacts** change after we add a new object in python-3?
I don't want to change the whole dictionary, I want to add a new object to it and the object also be added to the main code.

```
contacts = {'arman' : '123-355-1433',
            'samad' : '436-218-9818',}

print('hi welcom to my contacts.\nyou wanna check an existence contact or 
creat a new contact?')
creat_or_check = str(input())

if creat_or_check == 'check' :

    print('great, now who you wanna check?')
    contact_name = str(input())
    print(contacts[contact_name])

else :

    print('ok, now please first enter the name of the person then his number')
    enter_name = str(input('name : '))
    enter_number = str(input('number : '))
    contacts.update({enter_name : enter_number})
    print('the contact saved succesfully')
```

**e.x**

**from:**

```
contacts = {'arman' : '123-355-1433',
            'samad' : '436-218-9818',}
```

**to:**

```
contacts = {'arman' : '123-355-1433',
            'samad' : '436-218-9818',
            'person' : 'number' }
```

Comment: Whats wrong how you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the code, why don't you save the "contacts" in separate file like json file? For example:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

# check if file already exists, if not start with empty dict
if Path("contacts.json").is_file():
    contacts = json.load(open("contacts.json", "r"))
else:
    contacts={}

print('hi welcom to my contacts.\nyou wanna check an existence contact or creat a new contact?')
creat_or_check = str(input())

if creat_or_check == 'check':

    print('great, now who you wanna check?')
    contact_name = str(input())
    print(contacts[contact_name])

else:

    print('ok, now please first enter the name of the person then his number')
    enter_name = str(input('name : '))
    enter_number = str(input('number : '))
    contacts[enter_name] = enter_number
    json.dump(contacts, open("contacts.json", "w"))
    print('the contact saved succesfully')
```

Json file:

```
{
  "arman": "123-355-1433",
  "samad": "436-218-9818"
}
```

Comment: but it gives an error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ARMAN\code\python\projects\test\dict_test3.py", line 3, in <module>
    contacts = json.load(open("contacts.json", "r"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'contacts.json'

Answer (score 1):

You can actually add new things into your dictionary like this:

```
# original dictionary
contacts = {
 "arman": "123-355-1433",
  "samad": "436-218-9818"
}
contacts['NameHere'] = 0
```

And for the json one,something is missing.Code should be like this:

```
import json
filename = 'contacts.json'
try:
    with open(filename) as f_obj:
        contacts = json.load(f_obj)
except FileNotFoundError:
    contacts = {
 "arman": "123-355-1433",
  "samad": "436-218-9818"
}
with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
    json.dump(contacts, f_obj)

else:    
print('hi welcom to my contacts.\nyou wanna check an existence contact or creat a new contact?')
creat_or_check = str(input())

if creat_or_check == 'check':

    print('great, now who you wanna check?')
    contact_name = str(input())
    print(contacts[contact_name])

else:

    print('ok, now please first enter the name of the person then his number')
    enter_name = str(input('name : '))
    enter_number = str(input('number : '))
    contacts[enter_name] = enter_number
    json.dump(contacts, open("contacts.json", "w"))
    print('the contact saved succesfully')
```